# How to get height of first n cells in UITableVIew?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Say I want to limit table view's height constraint to show only particular number of top cells, how can I get their total height?

Comment: Add what you've tried so far.

Comment: Added an extension from my answer - works like a charm.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Swift 5:**

```
extension UITableView {

func height(of top: Int, in section: Int = 0) -> CGFloat {

    let count = min(top, numberOfRows(inSection: section))

    let height = (0..<count)
        .map { IndexPath(row: $0, section: section) }
        .map { self.rectForRow(at: $0).height }
        .reduce(0, +)

    return height
}
}
```

goes well with:

```
extension UITableView {

func reloadData(completion: @escaping () -> ()) {
    CATransaction.begin()
    CATransaction.setCompletionBlock(completion)
    reloadData()
    CATransaction.commit()
}
}
```

to update constraint after data is loaded.